# Wrong sorting on final step. function getColor

Tags: javascript, html, function, sorting, wrapper

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong when I send a variable to function as a wrap of the previous function.

The `function GetColor` must recive two values (`variable sort` and `variable a`) at the input and then compare them. If the some of the values of `a[i].getAttribute('href')` matches the values of `sort[i]` - print these `tags a` on the screen and paint these `tags a` inside the `DOM` in yellow color.

Now I'm get an odd sorting on the output of GetColor on the previously discarded value `"http://internal.com/"` in the `GetSort` func.

I think the error in my bad knowleges of transfering function arguments.

I will be thankful for your help.

```
<script>

    let a = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');

    function getList(list) { // creating an array from all a tag elements.

        let arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (a[i].getAttribute('href')) {
                arr.push(a[i].getAttribute('href'));        

            }
        }

        return arr;
    };

    function getSort(f) { // sort array given from getList() by symbols 'http'...

      let sorting;
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {

         if (f[i].includes('://') && !f[i].includes('http://internal.com/')) {
            console.log(f[i]);
            arr.push(f[i]);
         }
      }

      return arr; // [ "http://google.com" , "ftp://ftp.com/my.zip" , 
                    // "http://nodejs.org" ]
    };

    let sort = getSort(getList());

    console.log(sort);

    function getColor(sort) { // paint a tags based on sort elements from getSort()

        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].getAttribute('href') == sort[i]) {
                a[i].setAttribute('class', 'external'); // paint sorted a tags in DOM  
                                                        // by [external] attribute
                console.log(a[i]);

            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    getColor(a);



</script>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .external {
    background-color: yellow
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<a name="list">list</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
  <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
  <li><a href="ftp://ftp.com/my.zip">ftp://ftp.com/my.zip</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://internal.com/test">http://internal.com/</a></li>
</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question completely. Is the issue that only the links `ftp://ftp.com/my.zip` and `http://internal.com/` become yellow and that `http://google.com` does not? And should the result be that `ftp://ftp.com/my.zip` and `http://google.com` become yellow while `http://internal.com/` stays not yellow?

Comment: The result:
`<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>, 
<a href="ftp://ftp.com/my.zip">ftp://ftp.com/my.zip</a> , 
<a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a>` - must be in yellow

Comment: For now I'm get yellow for:
`<a href="ftp://ftp.com/my.zip">ftp://ftp.com/my.zip</a> and <a href="http://internal.com/test">http://internal.com/</a>` - that is strange

Comment: And I think that the problem is hide in soring of `getColor` function

Comment: `let sort = getSort(getList());` followed by `getColor(a);`.  You aren't using your `sort` variable anywhere.  Shouldn't the call to getColor be `getColor(sort);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright.

If you add some log statements, you can see exactly what's happening:

```js
    let a = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');

    function getList(list) { // creating an array from all a tag elements.

        let arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (a[i].getAttribute('href')) {
                arr.push(a[i].getAttribute('href'));        

            }
        }

        return arr;
    };

    function getSort(f) { // sort array given from getList() by symbols 'http'...

      let sorting;
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {

         if (f[i].includes('://') && !f[i].includes('http://internal.com/')) {
            console.log(f[i]);
            arr.push(f[i]);
         }
      }

      return arr; // [ "http://google.com" , "ftp://ftp.com/my.zip" , 
                    // "http://nodejs.org" ]
    };

    let sort = getSort(getList());

    function getColor(sort) { // paint a tags based on sort elements from getSort()

        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   console.log( 'a' );
   console.log( a[ i ] );
   console.log( a[ i ].getAttribute( 'href' ) );
   console.log( 'sort' );
   console.log( sort[ i ] );
   console.log( sort[ i ].toString() );
   console.log( a[ i ].getAttribute( 'href' ) == sort[ i ] );
   console.log( '-----' );
            if (a[i].getAttribute('href') == sort[i]) {
                a[i].setAttribute('class', 'yellow'); // paint sorted a tags in DOM  
                                                        // by [external] attribute
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    getColor(a);
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<a name="list">list</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
  <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
  <li><a href="ftp://ftp.com/my.zip">ftp://ftp.com/my.zip</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://internal.com/test">http://internal.com/</a></li>
</ul>
```

`a` is a nodelist defined outside your functions.
Then you create the `sort` array with `getSort()`

And then finally you call `getColor()` using `a` instead of `sort`.

So basically you're comparing `a` to itsself.

Since `a` contains html nodes, `sort` also contains html nodes.

So when you use `a[i].getAttribute( 'href' )` you get a string.
And then you compare that string with its own node.
Since you're using `==` ( compare value ) and not `===` ( comapre value And type ), the nodes in `sort` ( which is the same node as in `a` ) will call its own toString() function to cast it into a string.

As you can see in the console.log statements I added, the `href` attributes come back with a `/` at the end, if the link doesn't contain one yet ( as in http://internal.com/test )

And since `http://google.com/` is not the same as `http://google.com`, you get false. Same with `http://nodejs.org/` and `http://nodejs.org`.

So only `ftp://ftp.com/my.zip` and `http://internal.com/test` satisfy the condition and get printed in yellow.

If I had to write this, I would go for something like this.
It doesn't incldue the functions, but shows the workflow i'd follow.

```js
// 0) Get the array of tag elements.
const hyperlinks = document.querySelectorAll( 'a' );

// 1) Creating an array from all a tag elements.
const ary_hyperlinks = Array.from( hyperlinks );
// If your browser doesn't support Array.from(), you can use the slice method.
// const ary_hyperlinks = Array.prototype.slice.call( hyperlinks );

// 2) Sort array given from getList() by symbols 'http'.
// Since your code doesn't actually do any SORTING as we understand sorting, i'll just write what I think the question is.
// Since the assignment doesn't actually say that you have to reorder the elements in sorted order, this operation basically does nothing.
// If you have to reoder the elements while you color them yellow, we'd need to adjust the code.
const sorted_filtered_hyperlinks = ary_hyperlinks
  // Filter out all links that don't have a href attribute including http, ftp and that are not internal.
  .filter( function( node ) {
    const uri = node.getAttribute( 'href' );
    if ( uri ) return !uri.includes( 'internal' ) && uri.includes( 'http' ) || uri.includes( 'ftp' );
    else return false;
  } )
  // Sort the links by type. Since the type is the start of the href attribute of the link, this comes down to sorting the urls alphabetically
  .sort( function( first, second ) {
    // Alphabetically earlier eltters are smaller than later letters.
    if ( first.getAttribute( 'href' ) < second.getAttribute( 'href' ) ) return 1;
    else return -1;
  } ); 

// 3) paint a tags based on sort elements from getSort()
sorted_filtered_hyperlinks.forEach( function( node ) {
  node.setAttribute( 'class', 'yellow' );
} );
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<a name="list">list</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
  <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
  <li><a href="ftp://ftp.com/my.zip">ftp://ftp.com/my.zip</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://internal.com/test">http://internal.com/</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's so great! Thank you very much for so strong explanation!!! Cheers!

Comment: You can even do the whole script on one line by using a 'complicated' css selector. But that would mean not actually following the 3 steps: `Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'a:not([href*="internal"])[href^="http"],a:not([href*="internal"])[href^="ftp"]' ) ).forEach( node => node.setAttribute( 'class', 'yellow' ) );`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment your question and It is what i would like indeed to do. As shilly, your issue doesn't seem clear to me as well. 
But few issue in your code.

function **getList** : you specify a list parameter in the definition that you never use, better not to put i think. Personally, i will keep the parameter and avoid using outer scope variable inside my function a[i]... and make sure the function does its job only when passed an appropriate variable.

function **getSort** : if i follow well, it is just a funtion that construct a new array of link excluding links beginning with http://internal.com/ ? Rigth ? What the local variable sorting is then doing ? you never return it nor use it for anything inside you function.

function **getColor** : You call getColor(a), so bear in mind that a is passed by reference to getColor by mean of sort parmater. Hence in you getColor sort and a are the same. you are comparing same thing all time in you getColor function

Someone can say if i am wrong on all this. 
Write yours function to do their job, with their own arguments/parameters and avoid using any outer parameter directly them would be my advice